# Can this function be described by an easily computed recurrence?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

Define $g(n)$ for an integer $n \ge 2$ to be the smallest positive integer with the following properties:

- $g(n)$ is not divisible by 3
- For all $2\le k \le n$, we have $\gcd(4^k-1,g(n))>1$

Then $g(2)=5$, $g(3)=g(4)=35$, $g(5)=385$.  The growth of this function is relevant to the question of whether there are or are not infinitely many solutions to [the Freudenthal Problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300088/has-there-been-any-new-development-on-the-freudenthal-problem).

A naive way to define $g(n)$ as a recurrence is to first find the smallest factor $p$ of $(4^n-1)/3$ and then set $g(n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{11}
p g(n) & \gcd(p, g(n-1))=1\\
g(n) & \gcd(p, g(n-1))>1
\end{array}
\right.$

However, computing factorizations of large numbers gets difficult quickly.

It is clear that if $n$ is composite, $g(n)=g(n-1)$.  Using cycles of $r\rightarrow 4r+3 \pmod{2n+1}$ one can also show that if both $n$ and $2n+1$ are prime, $g(n)=(2n+1)g(n-1)$.

Where I am stumped is the case where $n$ is prime and $2n+1$ is composite.  In some instances, one has $g(n)=(cn+1)g(n-1)$ for some $c$, while in others $g(n)=\frac{2^n+1}{3}g(n-1)$.  For example, $g(37)/g(36)=223$, while $g(17)/g(16)=43691$.  I struggle to see why the former incurred a "small" factor, while the latter the worst case "large" factor, as $6*37+1=223$ and $6*17+1=103$ are both prime.

The question of the growth of $g(n)$ hinges on being able to predict how often it acquires a large factor of order $2^n$ rather than one of order $n$.  Is there something I am missing that makes this more readily computable/understandable?

Comment: Note: The sequence $a_n=g(n)$ is not yet in OEIS (nor is $a_n=g(p_n))$)

Comment: It looks as if a fast method to find $g(n)$ leads to a fast method to find the smallest prime divisor of $4^n-1$, hence the difficulty may be inherent.

Comment: Looking more at it, you are pretty certainly right.  This gives the smallest prime dividing $4^n-1$ which is a nontrivial thing to find.

I will look into existing work on Mersenne numbers.

My goal is to find $\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} g(n)\log(g(n))^{-4}4^{-n}$.  For small n this seems to blow up, but Mersenne numbers are good at lying about their trends while small.